# Search a file in unix system

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to find a file using find and locate commands.

`locate` command is faster but it requires to update the `slocate` db. And `find` command is slower but it wont require any updates.

I am trying to use a kind of `prd` systems.

Could anyone suggest a command which will be faster and can be used with initial level users for my shell script, please?

Comment: What is prd? Also, you somehow answered your own question : either use updatedb/locate so that searches per se will be faster, or use find which is slower but does not need updating a database first.

Comment: Can you give some info about the file you are looking for? Maybe that it can be found in just certain directories or such?

Comment: @schaiba.. prd- production systems. I am trying to find the xml files which will help us to get the information about the server configurations in customized manner and so tried to use find/locate commands to get the file list for my program.

Comment: @phk.. file names like resources.xml , libraries.xml etc from the WAS server unix systems

Answer (score 2):

Considering files are in a few subdirectories nested no more than two or three deep, so you can use a (possibly) faster command such as

```
(cd /path/to/directory; ls *.txt */*.txt */*/*.txt)
```

As you somehow managed to answer your own question use `updatedb` but with *speeding up locate*, like:

```
$ updatedb -o /home/rahul/my.db -U /home/rahul/ -e "not/in/this/directory1 not/in/this/directory2"
$ locate -d /home/rahul/my.db            ### point locate to use your db
```

see [updatedb man](http://linux.die.net/man/8/updatedb) for help on it.

---

As per @cas suggestion, alternatively, redirect the output of `find` to a file, and run `grep` on it repeatedly.  Plain text takes more space than an `updatedb` database but is much faster to search.

For example:

```
find /path/to/directory > /tmp/files.list
grep -i file.xml /tmp/files.list
grep -i anotherfile.xml /tmp/files.list
```

Comment: It would be simpler and faster just to save the output from `find` to a file, and then `grep` that if you needed repeated searches.  grepping a text file is MANY times faster than using `locate` on an `updatedb` database - I discovered this years ago with performance testing of my `dlocate` package and changed from generating an updatedb db for all installed package files to just generating a plain text file.  The text file takes more space, but that's the only (minor) disadvantage.

Comment: @cas ohh, could you please elaborate lil bit may be with some example if you could ? even you can update my post.

Comment: I have cron job on my systems that runs `locate / >/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.txt` after the main `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate` job has run, and a `qlocate` ("quick locate") script with various options to grep that.  The `mlocate.db` file takes 142MB on my system, while the `mlocate.txt` takes 447MB.

Comment: ok, added a very simple example to your answer.  feel free to edit it into your answer however you like.

Comment: @cas that's very cool. +1 for yours. Thanks

Comment: BTW, i just ran `time` on multiple runs of `mlocate` versus my `qlocate` script.   The `mlocate.db` and `mlocate.txt` files are stored in the same directory on a reasonably fast SSD.   `mlocate` takes 4.6 to 4.9 seconds to find a single file, doesn't seem to benefit from caching at all.  `qlocate` takes ~1.1 seconds on the first run, then ~0.4 seconds on subsequent (cached) runs.   `wc -l` says that `mlocate.txt` has 5,024,407 lines at the moment, i.e. that's how many files and dirs are on my system.

Comment: @cas that's awesome, I would try to use this method